# Getting wrong answer with using a recursion func that finds sum of a linked list in C

Tags: c, recursion, sum, singly-linked-list

I have two functions that finds sum of a very huge linked list.And recursive one does not give the true answer. 
(I have given the actual sum. So I know if the output is true or not)

My code:

```
float sum_linkedlist(numlist *head) {
  if(head!=NULL)
    return sum_linkedlist(head->next) + head->data;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot find what is wrong with my code.Can somebody help me?

Comment: Provide a minimal complete program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to explore its correctness with a short linked list. With a  huge one there is the very real possibilty that a recursive solution will cause stack overflow.

Comment: What is the expected and actual sum? How many elements in that list? Iterative solution in single function might have higher accuracy than float.

Comment: This code looks fine to me. Post a [mcve] that can be run to show the incorrect sum, please. Since you're using floats, make sure you understand [what to expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) when summing them.